# Adding a year to a time series with only months and days

Tags: r, time, time-series

I have a df like this

```
    month   day   x
1   1        1    84
2   1        2    43
3   1        3    49
4   1        4    67
5   1        5    59
......
366 12       31   97
```

The year should be 2019 from Oct-Dec and 2020 from Jan-Sep

I tried to use

```
df$year<-as.date(df,origin='2019-01-01')
```

But I am not sure how to make an argument.

I want the year column to get a date column and try then

```
df$date<-as.date(with(paste("???",month,day,sep="-"), %Y-%m-%d,origin ="2019-01-01")
```

but again I don't know how to make an argument for year

Please any help would save me a lot of time because doing it manually seems impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use an `ifelse` statement with the `make_date` function from lubridate:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(year= ifelse(month %in% c(10,11,12), 2019, 2020),
         date = make_date(year, month, day))
```

output:

```
    month day  x year       date
1       1   1 84 2020 2020-01-01
2       1   2 43 2020 2020-01-02
3      11   3 49 2019 2019-11-03
4       1   4 67 2020 2020-01-04
5       1   5 59 2020 2020-01-05
366    12  31 97 2019 2019-12-31
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like below. If you need a fixed variable instead of 2019/2020 you can use something like `var-1` when it is oct-dec and `var` when it is jan - sep.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = if_else(month %in% c(10:12),
                        ymd(paste(2019, df1$month, df1$day, sep = "-")),
                        ymd(paste(2020, df1$month, df1$day, sep = "-"))))
```

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(month = c(1:12), day = 1, x = 5)
```

Comment: Thank you that will also solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Using base features you could use `rowSums` to identify 31<sup>th</sup> of October, then `ISOdate`.

```
w <- which.max(rowSums(d[1:2]) == 31 + 10)

d$year <- c(rep(2020, w), rep(2019, 365 - w))

d$date <- do.call(\(year, month, day, ...) as.Date(ISOdate(year, month, day)), d)
```

### Result

```
head(d, 3)
#   month day  x year       date
# 1     1   1 58 2020 2020-01-01
# 2     1   2 74 2020 2020-01-02
# 3     1   3 43 2020 2020-01-03

tail(d, 3)
#     month day  x year       date
# 363    12  29 46 2019 2019-12-29
# 364    12  30 82 2019 2019-12-30
# 365    12  31 63 2019 2019-12-31
```

**Note:**

```
R.version.string
# [1] "R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)"
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L), 
    x = c(72L, 95L, 95L, 76L, 84L, 64L, 85L, 84L, 70L, 95L, 75L, 
    64L, 72L, 48L, 68L, 68L, 44L, 53L, 46L, 49L, 62L, 53L, 74L, 
    86L, 58L, 63L, 85L, 85L, 81L, 44L, 66L, 82L, 86L, 90L, 75L, 
    54L, 53L, 52L, 47L, 48L, 61L, 95L, 96L, 73L, 59L, 57L, 94L, 
    70L, 81L, 68L, 83L, 83L, 95L, 55L, 73L, 51L, 50L, 83L, 58L, 
    45L, 74L, 64L, 54L, 60L, 77L, 94L, 90L, 47L, 44L, 50L, 70L, 
    69L, 76L, 69L, 62L, 63L, 62L, 55L, 47L, 43L, 71L, 47L, 66L, 
    69L, 74L, 53L, 85L, 62L, 53L, 57L, 52L, 65L, 85L, 68L, 62L, 
    43L, 72L, 69L, 79L, 71L, 95L, 45L, 96L, 70L, 96L, 51L, 48L, 
    67L, 52L, 48L, 72L, 54L, 64L, 79L, 49L, 55L, 90L, 57L, 51L, 
    63L, 79L, 69L, 48L, 52L, 89L, 70L, 95L, 64L, 75L, 95L, 70L, 
    94L, 95L, 43L, 87L, 56L, 46L, 53L, 60L, 91L, 61L, 88L, 83L, 
    89L, 45L, 87L, 69L, 83L, 71L, 44L, 93L, 96L, 80L, 46L, 80L, 
    66L, 80L, 59L, 86L, 51L, 48L, 80L, 81L, 79L, 65L, 80L, 72L, 
    84L, 61L, 55L, 49L, 54L, 60L, 44L, 44L, 84L, 49L, 94L, 45L, 
    80L, 79L, 51L, 70L, 48L, 66L, 89L, 60L, 57L, 76L, 86L, 88L, 
    71L, 79L, 94L, 74L, 93L, 80L, 75L, 90L, 91L, 77L, 95L, 48L, 
    90L, 77L, 50L, 49L, 56L, 71L, 73L, 62L, 85L, 90L, 76L, 67L, 
    44L, 96L, 52L, 73L, 85L, 44L, 44L, 79L, 89L, 93L, 58L, 57L, 
    75L, 48L, 58L, 59L, 51L, 64L, 89L, 82L, 76L, 51L, 56L, 46L, 
    82L, 48L, 76L, 93L, 60L, 52L, 75L, 77L, 53L, 52L, 56L, 50L, 
    66L, 70L, 67L, 87L, 90L, 50L, 80L, 54L, 81L, 54L, 73L, 88L, 
    64L, 52L, 64L, 73L, 79L, 68L, 53L, 86L, 94L, 56L, 62L, 65L, 
    85L, 61L, 54L, 93L, 60L, 69L, 82L, 83L, 56L, 51L, 82L, 71L, 
    76L, 77L, 60L, 79L, 61L, 83L, 87L, 43L, 74L, 76L, 63L, 59L, 
    54L, 93L, 82L, 65L, 89L, 68L, 62L, 61L, 91L, 89L, 79L, 59L, 
    52L, 80L, 71L, 96L, 46L, 84L, 47L, 92L, 80L, 86L, 64L, 88L, 
    56L, 93L, 94L, 66L, 46L, 87L, 63L, 89L, 92L, 88L, 65L, 90L, 
    71L, 53L, 91L, 61L, 91L, 62L, 62L, 48L, 80L, 73L, 62L, 75L, 
    59L, 72L, 61L, 90L, 51L, 66L, 74L, 58L, 73L, 89L, 50L, 79L, 
    90L, 94L, 59L, 47L, 88L, 83L)), row.names = c(NA, -365L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R option -

```
transform(df, date = as.Date(paste(ifelse(month %in% 10:12, 2019, 2020), month, day, sep = '-')))

#    month day  x       date
#1       1   1 84 2020-01-01
#2       1   2 43 2020-01-02
#3      11   3 49 2019-11-03
#4       1   4 67 2020-01-04
#5       1   5 59 2020-01-05
```